# Convert PDF with images to Google Doc in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Apps Script and Google Drive API to convert a PDF file which is stored in my drive to Google Doc. The problem is, the PDF is converting to Google Doc but images and table formats are not coming in the newly generated doc, only texts and texts with colors are appearing.

My codes are given below:

```
function pdfToDoc() {
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFileById('MY_PDF_ID').getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true,
    convert: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I've been searching for solution in web but no luck. How can I convert a PDF perfectly to a Google Doc?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this is not possible. Google Drive uses basic [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) in order to transform the PDF into Docs, but it does not handle images - only text. If you are still interested in keeping the images you can:

- Call an external API that transforms PDF into DOC/DOCX files, and then upload it using `{convert:true}` to convert it into a Docs file. You can use [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for that (in this case, the conversion would work properly since it's from DOC/DOCX type to Docs type, not from PDF which is structured differenly).
- File a feature request within Google's [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com), so that this feature may be considered to be implemented.

Comment: Can you tell me some of the external APIs available for this? I've searched a lot but couldn't find a proper API that can convert PDF to DOC/DOCX.

Comment: @ShihanKhan I am not an expert on it and I have never used this sort of APIs, but after a quick search this one (https://www.docconversionapi.com/) seems like a good option. Cheers